# Sending a push event from webrick

Tags: ruby, push, push-notification, server-push, webrick

How can I send a push event via webrick? At certain timings, I want ruby to fire some events and send it to the browser via webrick. I can embed some JavaScript code on the page in advance.

Particularly, I am trying to implement one of the techniques written under *HTTP server push* and *Pushlet* on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sawa.

If you want to send some messages to your clients, try [Juggernaut2](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut).
Of course, you'll need to start separate [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)-based server to send notifications, but Juggernaut2 works with RoR really well.

Good luck.

Comment: I haven't look at it indetail, but it looks great. I will try it. Thank you.